# How to move point in Spatialite Layer through manual entry of X/Y coordinates?

Tags: spatialite

My Spatialite Database (Point Layer) looks like this (arch_locations.sqlite)

```
Fields:
pkuid
short_ID
name
geometry
X
Y
```

The field "X" and"Y" I added later (after first creation of DB) using the editing functions within the attribute table. They are of type "decimal number double" and I assigned the expressions $x and $y. Now they show X/Y Coordinates for viewing in an Access Database I have linked to the Spatialite Database through ODBC.

Is it possible for me to move a Point on the layer by manually changing the values in the X and Y column? I will have exact coordinates for some points while others will derive their location through digitalizing georeferenced scanned maps.

Devdatta Tengshe hinted that this might be possible in my other question.
Thanks for reading!

Edit to clear things up: 
I created the Database in QGIS through "Layer - new - spatialite Layer". I set it to Point and geometry and digitalized some points on a georeferenced map.
Then I wanted to have two columns which show me X/Y Coordinates to be viewed in Access. I asked here how to do it:
[How to add columns with x/y data to Spatialite Layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94375/how-to-add-columns-with-x-y-data-to-spatialite-layer)

Following this advice I went to the attribute table of the layer, enabled editing and added two columns. Then I used the field calculator to put in the two new columns the expressions $x and $y.

Now I only want to move some of the points I digitalized to an exact position by entering the x/y coordinates in those two columns. It doesn´t matter if I have to add the coordinated somewhere else I just want some points to be moved slightly.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you doing this directly in spatialite? Or are you using some graphical application? How did you produce a spatialite table using ODBC? If it really is in spatialite, you can use a trigger, but this type of problem indicates a database design issue - you should probably use a view instead. Can you edit your question with a bit more detail on how you got to here?

Comment: @BradHards: Taya had posted a question earlier which explains what they are trying to achieve: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94375/how-to-add-columns-with-x-y-data-to-spatialite-layer You can look at the edits on that question to figure out the whole context.

Comment: @Taya: This should be possible with an Update trigger. I'll try to post a solution in a day or so.

Comment: I still think the view is the right answer.

Comment: Looking forward to your answer, Devdatta. Please remember that I´m quite new at QGIS. Sometimes I still even don´t know where to find specific submenus and so on :)
@BradHards: I´ll read up on whats possible with a view.