# Adding columns with Lat / Lon data to Spatialite Layer in EPSG 32632?

Tags: spatialite

I've a point layer in ESPG 32632 spatial reference in my SpatiaLite database.

To add X and Y columns I've used [Adding columns with x/y data to SpatiaLite Layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94375/how-to-add-columns-with-x-y-data-to-spatialite-layer) and it works fine.

Now I need to add also Lat and Lon columns to store coordinates in EPSG4326.

Any example?

Comment: A good question should include your attempt and detail of what happens when you try it.  What have you tried?  Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is basically the same [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/237052/22405). Execute the following SQL expressions:

```
ALTER TABLE points ADD COLUMN LON double;
ALTER TABLE points ADD COLUMN LAT double;
UPDATE points SET LON=ST_X(ST_Transform(geometry,4326));
UPDATE points SET LAT=ST_Y(ST_Transform(geometry,4326));
```