# Adding columns to existing SpatiaLite layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I have created a SpatiaLite point layer in QGIS with each point having attribute NAME. I have since realised it would be useful to have a text field for NAME of notes/description. I have looked at this question [Adding columns Lat,Lon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236986/adding-columns-with-lat-lon-data-to-spatialite-layer-in-epsg-32632) but have no experience of where/how to enter the SQL expressions mentioned.

How do you populate the TEXT field once created?

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries can be executed using the DB Manager, take a look at: [Lesson: Using DB Manager to work with Spatial Databases in QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/databases/db_manager.html).

Populating the table can be done by editing and typing the values into the attribute table, using the Field Calculator, and by INSERT
statements in the DB Manager see: [Editing attribute values](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#editing-attribute-values)

Comment: I added the extra fields following the instructions but they did not show up when I clicked on "Open Attribute Table". When I tried to save it all the existing data was deleted.

Comment: You might have to readd the layer to QGIS for new fields to show

Comment: Bera, I'm familiar with a fair bit of QGIS but have never tried to edit a QGIS database.  "read the layer to QGIS" conveys nothing to me.  I added the extra fields easily after reading your link but as said they didn't show in QGIS and I lost all entered data.  I have now started to recreate the layer but starting with a properly thought out database field set.  Time is pressing but I will return to attempting editing  when there is less presure.

Comment: Did you have the GeoPackage layer open in the project while you were editing it with the DB Manager?

Comment: Yes, open whilst editing in DB Manager.

Comment: Have a try by closing the layer from the project before adding a new field with DB manager. The change in the schema may be queued because of the ACID principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID. If you have an open connection, then another connection should not add/remove fields so that the first connection is not aware. I am not sure it this is correct but test it.

Comment: I made a simple test and it looks like closing and re-opening the layer in the project window after you have edited the schema should work. The attribute table appeared empty also for me, but after re-opening all the data are there.

Comment: Closing and opening layer?  I thought you could only edit (colours, labels etc or delete.  Or does highlighting another layer count as closing?